# Making Juice "Bread" During Passover

Tags: passover, matzah

I was thinking of making non-chametz bread during passover using wine, milk or other non water liquids, and the issue wether or not there might be water added, intentionally or accidentally to such processed liquids came up.

For example, Rambam says in [הלכות חמץ ומצה פרק ה,ב](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/3505.htm#2):

> חמשת מיני דגן אלו--אם לשן במי פירות בלבד, בלא שם מים בעולם--אינם באין לידי חימוץ; אלא אפילו הניחן כל היום עד שנתפח כל הבצק, הרי זה מותר באכילה:  שאין מי פירות מחמיצין, אלא מסריחין.  ומי פירות, הן כגון יין וחלב ודבש וזית ומי תפוחים ומי רימונים וכל כיוצא בהן משאר יינות ושמנים ומשקין--והוא, שלא יתערב בהן שם מים בעולם; ואם נתערב בהן מים כל שהוא, הרי אלו מחמיצין.
>
> These five grains -- if they are kneaded in fruit juice only, with no water ever added -- they don't become hametz; even if one left them the whole days until they rose like dough, see it is permissible to eat: that fruit juice doesn't make something hametz, instead it [ makes it smelly? ].  And fruit juice, it is such as wine, milk, honey, olive, apple juice, pomegranate juice and all such wine's, oils and liquids -- and this, only if no water has ever mixed with them; and if any water whatsoever has mixed with them, see they become hametz.

So I was searching regarding milk production in Israel and ran across the following [on the Tnuva website](http://kashrut-tnuva.co.il/milk_page.php?actions=show&id=212):

> חלב תנובה אינו נמהל במים, ולכן לכאורה אין כל חשש לשרות מצה בחלב גם למחמירים בשרויה. אך כמו שלגבי יין נפסק בשו"ע או"ח סימן תס"ב שאי אפשר ליין בלי טיפת מים הנופלת בשעת הבציר, כך אי אפשר להבטיח שבחלב לא נכנסו מעט מים, שהרי צנרת החלב עוברת שטיפות יסודיות בין ייצור לייצור. אשר על כן, לגבי לישת קמח בחלב, הדבר תלוי לכאורה במחלוקת האחרונים לגבי ביטול מעט מים במי פירות מרובים, ולהלכה, יש להחמיר
>
> Tnuva's milk is not diluted with water, and therefore in light of this there is no worry to soak matza in milk even for those who are stringent with soaking.  However, just as in regards to wine it is the opinion of the Shulchan Aruch that it is impossible to make wine without a drop of water falling in during the harvest, similarly it is impossible to guarantee that a little water didn't get into the milk, since the milk pipes are thoroughly washed between production batches.  **Therefore, regarding kneading flour with milk, the issue depends as it seems on a dispute of the later sages regarding the negation of a little water in vast quantities of fruit juice, and the practice is to be stringent.**

I'm curious if anyone can provide sources for the above mentioned dispute.

I understand that the [Papouchado cookies](http://www.papouchado.co.il/?id=118) are made in this manner and where permitted by Rav Ovadia Yosef, although I don't know if they are prepared in less than 18 minutes.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56978/759

Comment: http://etzion.org.il/vbm/english/archive/moadim70/02-70moed.htm

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes - link is broken, I think.  It doesn't seem to have anything to do with this.